# Extract lines from user's input paragraphs

Tags: python, input

I get a user input using:

```
paragraphInput = input ("paste your paragraph ")
print(paragraphInput)
```

I get:

```
Line 1 of the paragraph
Line 2 of the paragraph
Line 3 of the paragraph
Line 4 of the paragraph
```

I would like to have displayed something like this:

```
This is Line 1 of the paragraph !
This is Line 2 of the paragraph !
This is Line 3 of the paragraph !
This is Line 4 of the paragraph !
```

So I wanted to use a `for` loop but I don't know how to retrieve the line "n"  of the paragraph and then to add in front of it `This is` and after it `!` . Is there a way of doing this ? Because the number of lines of the paragraphs will change depending on the user ...

Thanks for taking the time to read and for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has a function to split lines of a string.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines

For example, 
`'ab c\n\nde fg\rkl\r\n'.splitlines()` 
returns 
`['ab c', '', 'de fg', 'kl'],`

Then you can just iterate through this list that now has proper line breaks.

```
for line in paragraphInput.splitlines():
    print "This is " + line + " !"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
for line in paragraphInput.split('\n'):
    print "This is " + line + " !"
```

Comment: str.splitlines() is a better function to use since it'll catch other line breaks that aren't just "\n"

Comment: I tried this, and it displays:
This is Line 1 of the paragraph
Line 2 of the paragraph
Line 3 of the paragraph
Line 4 of the paragraph !

Comment: @MatthiasGrahamSlick that means your input doesn't contain `\n`, so the loop is only running once.  You can try AdriVelaz's `str.splitlines()` solution instead.